# Best way to handle Null-able navigation properties on my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
        @model IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TMSVirtualMachine>
        <td>
@(item.TechnologyBackUpStatu == null ? "None" : item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.Name )        

@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.Name)
        </td>
```

the `TechnologyBackUpStatus` is a NullAble navigation property , which means that the model might not have a `TechnologyBackUpStatus`, so currently i am using two ways of displaying the `item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.Name )` . but why apprach i should consider ; using the `DisplayFor` or usig the  `? :` and why onr apprach is better comparing to the other ?

Thanks

Comment: if its nullable then you have to use item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.HasValue to check for null and item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.Value to access value

Answer (score 2):

Using `DisplayFor` allows DataAnnotation usage, for formatting purpose for example. It is better to use it than a raw `@item.TechnologyBackUpStatu.Name`.

As your navigation property is a complex type, you can build a `DisplayTemplate` where you choose how to display your entity, like this :

Your template : `Shared/DisplayTemplates/TechnologyBackUpStatu.cshtml`

```
@model MyNamespace.TechnologyBackUpStatu

@if(Model != null)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

Then, in your main view :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TechnologyBackUpStatu)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is you just create another property, it only gets the value from "TechnologyBackUpStatu" if it has a value.

Below is an example, to do this, you need to enable Lazy Loading, also ignore the property in your DbContext class.

**In your Model:**

```
public class TMSVirtualMachine
 {
     public int? TechnologyBackUpStatuId { get; set; }

     public string TechnologyBackUpStatuName
     {
         get
         {
             return TechnologyBackUpStatuId.HasValue ? 
                        TechnologyBackUpStatu.Name : "None";
         }
     }
     public virtual TechnologyBackUpStatu TechnologyBackUpStatu { get; set; }
 }
```

**In your view:**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.TechnologyBackUpStatuName)
```

**In your DbContext class**

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<TMSVirtualMachine>().Ignore(n => n.TechnologyBackUpStatuName);
   }
}
```